# Making new custom relation method in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am using this for my api when i visit someone profile:

```
return response()->
json(
    User::load(["posts.comments"])
    ->where('username', request('username'))
    ->firstOrFail()
);
```

Now when I want to use paginate on relation I do it like this:

```
$user->posts()->paginate(10);
```

But I need relation so I found:

```
$user->setRelation('posts', $user->posts()->paginate(10));
```

Now I am wondering is there a way to create custom relation method inside model so when I use `load(['posts.comments'])` it returns that custom relations?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do this:

```
return response()->
json(
    User::with(['posts' => function($q) {
        $q->paginate(5);
    }, 'posts.comments' => function($q) {
        $q->paginate(5, ['*'], 'commentsPage', request('commentsPage'));
    }])
    ->where('username', request('username'))
    ->firstOrFail()
);
```

Although I am not sure how to pass `$q->nextPageUrl()`